# Should I WX(drop) a class if the highest grade I can get is a B+? How badly would this hurt my PhD application?

Tags: phd, computer-science

I'm an undergraduate right now and in my junior year. I was overloading courses and fell behind one course, leaving me with a B+ as the highest possible grade for the course. Should I retake it next year if I know I can get an A in the class?

Also: it is a core class and I can technically get an A- but thats with a 100 on everything...

Comment: Is the course in your major or outside of it? A "core" course or an elective?

Comment: From the edit history, it seems that you have two accounts: you can [merge them](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: So, a B+ is a stretch. Remember, a C in grad school is failing.

Comment: What does I WX(drop) mean?

Comment: @CapeCode: WX is probably the school's code for "withdrawal" from a course (that is, dropping the course in the middle of a term).

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Dave Rose that the most important aspects of your application will be your thesis and advisor recommendation, but I want to take a slightly more nuanced angle on whether you should drop your course.

You say that a B+ is the highest grade you can receive. Is it the likely grade? You should not be basing your estimates of what you are going to get in the class on statements like "if I get perfect scores on the remaining exams I can get . . .". If, in fact, you are more likely to get a C+, and the course is a "core" course, then an argument can be made for you to drop until the next time it is offered.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not! you should not drop the course for next year, do not waste your time on this. B+ and A is not that far apart if other marks are high. The most important thing to remember is to have an A in your thesis and a good recommendation letter from your supervisor you did your project/thesis with.

Comment: Not every has a thesis in their undergraduate work. In fact: I've never encountered such a thing anywhere IME. I didn't know until this second that undergraduate theses were given letter grades.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Not all of them are.